# Add first name and last name automatically on facebook registration for wordpress user

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code to create a facebook user when logging with a facebook connect button:

```
if($_REQUEST['option'] == "fblogin"){
    global $wpdb;
    $appid      = get_option('afo_fb_app_id');
    $appsecret  = get_option('afo_fb_app_secret');
    $facebook   = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appid,
        'secret' => $appsecret,
        'cookie' => TRUE,
    ));
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($fbuser) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
        $user_fbid  = $fbuser;
        $user_email = $user_profile["email"];
        $user_fnmae = $user_profile["first_name"];

      if( email_exists( $user_email )) { // user is a member 
          $user = get_user_by('login', $user_email );
          $user_id = $user->ID;
          wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
       } else { // this user is a guest
          $random_password = wp_generate_password( 10, false );
          $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_email, $random_password, $user_email);
          wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
       }

        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;

    }       
}
```

The user is created well with the email but the name from the facebook profile is missing. I don't know how to send it to the `wp_create_user` to make it.

I tried something like this with no luck (added $user_fnmae):

```
       } else { // this user is a guest
          $random_password = wp_generate_password( 10, false );
          $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_email, $random_password, $user_email, $user_fnmae );
          wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
       }
```

Any idea where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

[wp_create_user() Wordpress doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

Try this:

```
$user_id = wp_create_user($user_fnmae , $random_password, $user_email);
```

Take care with the mistype: `user_fnmae => user_fname`

**EDIT:**

If you need you set another values (e.g. first_name, last_name, display_name, ...), use: [wp_insert_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $user_email,
    'user_pass'   =>  $random_password,
    'first_name'  =>  $user_fnmae
);
wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

Comment: It works but not the solution I'm looking for. If I put it that way, the first name of the new user is used as `username` but it isn't taken for the first name field. Also last name is missing :(